# Django Customizing authentication user results in 2 fields in admin

Tags: django, templates, admin

I've followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model to add a ManyToMany field for what games a user has played.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    """ Extended authentication profile storing specific info """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    owned = models.ManyToManyField(OwnedStruct)
```

then add to admin by the following

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """ Show profile inline with user """
    model = Profile
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """ Add inline to User """
    inlines = (ProfileInline,)
...
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

In the database things look fine, but in the admin I see two fields representing the ManyToMany OwnedStruct. Before messing with the user, it shows the first as "Profile #1" and the second as "Profile #2". After selecting some options from Profile 1's M2M and clicking save, it appears to update that field correctly. If I update Profile#2, it does not save or work or appear to change anything. I'd expect it to only show one. What could cause two Profiles?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the problem is that for some reason django admin doesn't care about `OneToOneField` and create more than one inline forms for the `Profile`. You can try to fix that with adding `max_num = 1` to your `ProfileInline` class.

It must look something like:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """ Show profile inline with user """
    model = Profile
    max_num = 1
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'
```

Comment: I was kind of thinking that too, so I tried that a bit ago to no avail. (Also with editable=false.)

Comment: When I tried your code even without `max_num` it works as it should. I tested it with Django 1.6.1. Are you using some custom app for fancy administration?

Comment: 'Django==1.5', 'python-memcached', 'beautifulsoup4', 'South', 'django-registration', 'django-bootstrap3' well thanks for trying it out, maybe I'll try on a different machine later or something.